# How do I alter my role to be a superuser?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, ubuntu

I'm working my way through the steps in [this](http://erictheise.github.io/geostack-deck/#/28) slide to configure Postgresql & PostGIS.

I configured my user role as directed on [this](http://erictheise.github.io/geostack-deck/#/15/1) slide. Note, the new role should not be a superuser.

That brings me to my current problem. How do I alter my role to be a superuser? In the image below, you can see I'm connected to `template_postgis` using my role (also my system account name as instructed on the above slide). When I try to create the extension postgis, I get a `permission denied` message.

[image]

Comment: You can't become a superuser if you're not a superuser. Google "postgresql reset password"

Comment: Simply log in as `postgres` and `ALTER ROLE youruser WITH SUPERUSER`